# Hit the getStats api on webrtc app built using Daily.co and get the statistics for on on going call

Tags: webrtc

I am using [daily.co](https://www.daily.co/) for creating an audio/video conference application using React-Typescript. I am unable to get the RTCPeerConnection object to hit the getStats API. Any pointers or references where I should be looking for?

Webrtc app: https://www.daily.co/

Comment: Hey! Phil (from Daily) here, did you figure this out or is it still an issue? Apologies for taking so long to notice your question. Which stats in particular are you trying to access?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thanks :)